# WPF with UI threading issues - TaskFactory, CollectionView issues - syntax nightmare

Tags: wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await, collectionview

See bottom of post for my pseudo solution.

Once again I'm completely and utterly stuck on this. I've burned hours trying to understand - and yes I can get a single collectionviewsource to work beautifully with nothing about threading on the code behind.

Imagine my shock when I found merely adding two collectionviewsources on the page causes threading issues. I've spent a few hours last night reading Async in C#5 and the MSDN stuff however I get into work today and I can't decipher how to make this happen.

The code below is the last attempt I've made before whining for help as I've burnt, possibly, a bit too much work time on attempting to understand how to do this. I understand that I need one collectionviewsource to complete before starting the other, so I tried Await Task.ContinueWith etc to try and chain one after the other.

Lining up both sets of tasks in the threads correctly seems to be quite tricky, or I'm still misunderstanding something fundemental.

If anyone can advise how they would asynchronously populate a few controls on a WPF UI I would be very grateful.

The application itself is a throwaway application, linked to an Access database that I'm using to try and become fluent enough in threading to implement it in our proper code base. I'm long way off that!

Updated with more complete code samples and the adjustments made according to answers:

```
Private Async Sub MainWindowLoaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
InitializeComponent()

Dim personSetViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("personSetViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
Dim contactSetViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("contactSetViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)

Dim personList = Await Task.Run(Function() personSet.personList)
personSetViewSource.Source = personList

Dim contactList = Await Task.Run(Function() contactSet.contactList)
contactSetViewSource.Source = contactList

End Sub`
```

The ObservableCollectionEx class:

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (BlockReentrancy())
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler collectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;
        if (collectionChanged != null)
            foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in collectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
            {
                DispatcherObject dispObj = nh.Target as DispatcherObject;
                if (dispObj != null)
                {
                    Dispatcher dispatcher = dispObj.Dispatcher;
                    if (dispatcher != null && !dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    {
                        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh1 = nh;
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                            (Action) (() => nh1.Invoke(this,
                                                       new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                                                           NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))),
                            DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                nh.Invoke(this, e);
            }
    }
}
}
```

Please note, I can't translate this class to VB due to requiring an Event Override.
Another variation I've tried, but falls foul of thread ownership again. The two collectionviews thing isn't yielding to a solution: I don't know if it's because the underlying collection isn't good for it or whether in reality it wasn't meant to work that way. I get close but no cigar.

```
 Dim CarePlanList = Task.Run(Function() CarePlanSet.CarePlanList)
    Dim rcpdList = Task.Run(Function() rcpdSet.rcpdList)

    Dim tasks() As Task = {CarePlanList, rcpdList}
    Dim t = New TaskFactory
    Await t.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, Sub()
                                       carePlanSetViewSource.Source = CarePlanList
                                       rcpdSetViewSource.Source = rcpdList
                                   End Sub)
```

I found a way to do it, based on a combination of feedback and research this morning. Building the two collectionviews asynchronously itself is somewhat impractical given the STAThread model of WPF. However, merely ensuring one HAS completed and shifting some of the async out of one entity class has made this plausible.

Instead I fire off the first task, who's underlying class does build it's data with its own Async method. Then test to see if it has completed before allowing the second collectionview to be fired off. This way I don't need to worry about context or dispatcherobjects. The second collection does not use any async.

```
    Dim personList = Task(Of List(Of person)).Run(Function() personSet.personList)
    Dim contactList = Task(Of ObservableCollectionEx(Of contact)).Run(Function() contactSet.contactList)

    contactSetViewSource.Source = contactList.Result
    If contactList.IsCompleted Then personSetViewSource.Source = personList.Result
```

This is an experimental project for concept research really. As it happens, the idea I'd want two such lists built this way isn't as useful as all that but I do see where being able to compose a data heavy interface asynchronously could be handy.

Comment: You say you're reading up on C# 5, but then your code is VB. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: @Jon Skeet The Async book is C# only, however the MSDN is VB which is the language I have to use at work. Outside of Async/Threading I'm comfortable with lambdas etc in both languages - partly due to your book on C# which is nicely dog eared now! I'm furiously hunting through the answers and snippers on SO and elsewhere trying to crack the syntax puzzle of how to do this - quite a frustrating experience. Last night I started from threads and played, then moved onto tasks and the TPL. But it's not translating well at all when I move into WPF.

Comment: what is exactly the issue? what goes wrong?

Comment: @fix_likes_coding Everything! LOL. I've spent a lot of time trying to get my head around the syntax. The theory I read is fine, but arranging the words in code is really getting to me on this specific subject. The example I'm fighting with is only 2 collectionviewsources that each have their own async methods. These work fine - if the code behind only asks for one. So cracking this principle is quite essential to me, even though this specific app is only experimental. The syntax blindness is standard for me unfortunately.

Comment: When you use data binding, you need to treat all your viewmodels (in this case, the `CollectionViewSource`s) as though they were part of the UI. The code you posted (setting `Source`) should run on the UI thread. Why are you trying to do anything on the background thread?

Comment: @StephenCleary one of the operations is longer running, so I want the app built before it completes. If I only do the one collectionviewsource, this works just fine. So I'm sure I'm either missing out on using await correctly or dispatcherobject.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just realised the name tags don't notify if I get them slightly wrong :).

Comment: @Richard How could the operations be longer running? All they do is to assign a property. And if you mean that it takes a long time to render them, then running the operation on a background thread won't help you, rendering has to run on the UI thread.

Comment: @svick The collectionviewsource is a record list of 2000 items fed from an Access database by a class that uses Async methods to populate itself. My assumption had been when the first source worked fine, the second would too. Either one alone will work. The screen renders and the list populates, taking a few seconds, where I can interact with the form whilst the list loads.

Comment: @Richard: I suspect it may be how the "populate itself" is being done. Could you post this code?

Comment: @StephenCleary , it is a thin wrapper round a oledb object that is an ms access database link. Ill post this when I have the source in my hand in the morning :)

Comment: @StephenCleary This is the basic code that populates the list. It's only fired when empty. `Private Shared Sub BuildPeopleList()
        db.newcmd("Select * from  people where retired = false ")
        While db.read
            Dim people As New Person
            With people 
                .id = db.dbint("ID")
                .Name = db.dbin("Name")
               End With
_PeopleList.add(person)
End while`

Comment: @Richard: I'm missing the part where it's using async methods to populate itself.

Comment: @StephenCleary the underlying class uses this: `Private Shared Async Sub BuildPeopleListAsync()
        Await Task.Run(Sub() BuildPeopleList())
        Return
    End Sub`

Comment: @StephenCleary the property that collectionviewsource uses conditionally fires the async method if it hasn't already been populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two code samples each have issues that jump out right away.

In the first you are awaiting `task1`, I assume with more code following, but all `task1` is doing is starting what is basically a fire and forget operation back to the UI thread (`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`), therefore not really producing anything asynchronous to await.

In the second, the primary issue seems to be that you are doing a lot of setup of `Task` instances and chaining them with continuations but never starting the `action2 Task`, which appears to be the root of the whole chain, hence getting no activity at all. This is similar to what you get with a `BackgroundWorker` that never has `RunWorkerAsync` called.

To get this working properly and avoid making your head spin any more I would suggest starting by writing this whole block without any async and verifying that everything loads as expected, but with the UI lockup you want to avoid. Async/Await is designed to be added into code like that with minimal structural changes. Using `Task.Run` along with async and await you can then make the code asynchronous.

Here's some pseudocode for the basic pattern, without async to start:

```
PersonSetList = LoadData1()
CVS1.Source = PersonSetList
ContactList = LoadData2()
CVS2.Source = ContactList
```

and now adding async:

```
PersonSetList = await Task.Run(LoadData1())
CVS1.Source = PersonSetList
ContactList = await Task.Run(LoadData2())
CVS2.Source = ContactList
```

What this will now do is start a task to load the person data and immediately return from your WindowLoaded method, allow the UI to continue rendering. When that data is loaded it will continue to the next line *on the original thread* and push the data into the UI (which may itself slow down the UI while rendering). After that it will do the same for the Contact data. Notice that Dispatcher isn't needed explicitly because await is returning back to the UI thread for you to complete its continuation.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this and thought it should work. However I have "An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source" issue. Either one works perfectly on its own. `Dim PersonList = Await Task.Run(Function() PersonSet.PersonList)
        PersonSetViewSource.Source = PersonList

        Dim contactList = Await Task.Run(Function() contactSet.contactList)
        contactSetViewSource.Source = contactList`

Comment: Removed my additional comment in favour of clarifying my question with the code!

Comment: That error message indicates a problem with updating bound collections from a background thread. Are the PersonList and similar properties being populated from the background after assigning?

Comment: yes they are. Works fine for one, I just need to hold up the other one til the first is done. Hence my trying tricks like continuation etc.

Comment: Since that is the case you've basically ceded all control of the asynchrony to the code inside PersonSet, etc. You might want to try updating those to be awaitable so you can control them like in the example above. Otherwise you're going to need to implement some sort of exclusive locking mechanism in those data sources to prevent them from all independently sending updates to the UI at the exact same time, which I think is what is actually causing your problem.

Comment: So too much async all Round then. Ill try this in the morning now. Gone cross eyed. Thank you though!